# Set CustomPainter LineDrawer above all widgets

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I started working on a sort of Visual Scripting Widget in Flutter.
It is coming along quite nicely, but I have one problem.
The lines I draw between Nodes are sometimes behind other widgets.
[image: Visualization of the problem]

I use a Stack and The Positioned widget as a "Coordinate System" to display my Nodes.
This means some widgets are technically behind others. Which causes the lines to render behind other widgets.
Since the CustomPainter uses local space, I would like it to stay in the widget tree, as it makes the connections stable even in a ScrollView.

Is there a way to force the lines to render on top?
In Unity, I would just use a shader, but I'm not sure how to achieve this with the shader implementation of Flutter.

The project is not cleaned or tested at this point, but if you want to take a look, here is the repo:
https://github.com/Cunibon/visual_scripting

Comment: and where is your `CustomPaint`? as a parent of the `Stack`?

Comment: There is a custom painter as a parent of every node. Output or input

Comment: and this is your problem: it should be one `CustomPaint` widget  - a parent of the `Stack` with all the children - or even better `Flow` instead of `Stack`

Comment: or alternatively you could use this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_painter-dart - a simple wrapper with 77 lines (where 1/4 are doc comments)

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in the ticket I would like to keep the customPaint on the widget as I can then use localSpace coordinates. This makes the connections stable even when inside scrollviews.

I will check out the package though